# Unit testing compile-time weaving

Tags: java, spring, junit, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am using the [aspectj maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) to weave Aspects at compile time. When I run the application, the class with the `@Advice` annotation is being instantiated just before the first time the advice is called. For example:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAdviceClass {

    public MyAdviceClass() {
        System.out.println("creating MyAdviceClass");
    }

    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(timed)")
    public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Timed timed) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("timed annotation called");
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

If I have a method using the `@Timed` annotation, the "creating MyAdviceClass" will be printed the first time that method is called and "timed annotation called" will be printed every time.

I would like to unit test the functionality of the advice by mocking some components in `MyAdviceClass` however can not do this because `MyAdviceClass` is instantiated by AspectJ just in time, not through Spring Beans.

What is the best practice method for unit testing something like this?

Comment: Usually unit tests involve mocking external dependencies, but I don't see any.   I'm guessing you want to mock some external dependencies?  Or do you want to mock the advice?

Comment: Create a `MyAdviceClass` instance using its constructor, use mocks for `ProceedingJoinPoint` and `Timed`?

Comment: @Taylor, I have excluded them for simplicity. @RC., you are correct that I could test the `doBasicProfiling` method that way, but I would also like to test that the advice is called when I execute an annotated method.

Comment: The easiest way is to mock an externality of the aspect (some service/dao/whatever it calls), inject that, and verify that it's called as you expect

Comment: Yes, exactly. Unfortunately since AspectJ is creating the instance the first time it is needed rather than through a Spring Bean, I can not find the instance that it creates in order to do that injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and would like to post it for anyone else that encounters this. The trick is using `factory-method="aspectOf"` in your spring bean definition. So using the example above, I would add this line to my `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean class="com.my.package.MyAdviceClass" factory-method="aspectOf"/>
```

Any my unit test would look something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
public class MyAdviceClassTest {
    @Autowired private MyAdviceClass advice;
    @Mock private MyExternalResource resource;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initMocks(this);
        advice.setResource(resource);
    }

    @Test
    public void featureTest() {
        // Perform testing
    }
}
```

More details are available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s08.html#aop-aj-configure).